# I cannot access my supabase table from my app

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, material-ui, formik, supabase-database

Currently I have my insertIntoDB function that takes in values from my formik/MUI form.

```
import { supabase } from '../../../Utilities/SupabaseClient';

export const insertIntoDB = async (values) => {
  let error;
  try {
    error = await supabase.from('supplier_initial_assessment_1').insert([{
      comapny_name: values.companyName,
      climate_change_policy: values.climateChangePolicy,
      climate_change_policy_description: values.climateChangePolicyDescription,
      climate_team_responsible: values.climateTeamResponsible,
      climate_team_description: values.climateTeamDescription,
      currently_measure_emissions: values.currentlyMeasureEmissions,
      currently_measured_emissions_program_description:
        values.currentlyMeasuredEmissionsProgramDescription,
      scopes_measured_description: values.scopesMeasuredDescription,
      emissions_data_stored_description: values.emissionsDataStoredDescription,
    }],{ returning: "minimal" });

    console.log(values);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error message', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

When I try to submit I get the following error in the dev console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHYEj.png)

I have tried setting the table RLS to:

```
BEGIN;
  ALTER POLICY "Enable insert for authenticated users only" ON "public"."supplier_initial_assessment_1" WITH CHECK (false);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: 400 error shows your request is invalid.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual error you are getting. There should be a body to the 400 error response you are getting which should tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Is the RLS that you have shared there the only policy that you have? If so, it doesn't seem like you are allowing any inserts for anyone. You need an RLS policy that will evaluate to `true` to allow inserts.